# How to save a series of matplotlib plots as an image file?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I'm trying to save a series of matplotlib figures as one single image file with many slices. To put things in perspective, the following is the code I'm using:

```
for n in range(len(image.shape[0])): #this image here is a timelapse image
   plt.imshow(image[n, :, :], cmap='gray')
   ax = plt.gca()
     for acontour in contour_list:
         ax.add_patch(patches.Polygon(acontour[:, [1, 0]],linewidth=1,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none'))       
     plt.show()
```

I'm trying to overlay the corresponding contour on the original image for every slice and save all the images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a little unclear from your question what you mean by "slice". Your opening paragraph talks about a *single* file, but the last paragraph talks about multiple images. Perhaps you need to specify what image format you're aiming for (maybe .mng?). You might also want to look at `plt.savefig()` in the matplotlib library?

Answer (score 0):

Will this help:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,len(image.shape[0])//2, figsize=(15, 6))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .5, wspace=.001)
axs = axs.ravel()

for n in range(len(image.shape[0])):
    # Your plot code
    
plt.savefig('image.png')
```